# Is doing pure HTML+JS applications with .NET webservices viable and secure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

For our latest projects, we've used MVC5 with Angularjs+Ninject+Bootstrap and other techs, and we have ended up with applications that take us a long time to fix bugs and add features, with more tiers (and tears) than necessary.

Is it viable to make Pure HTML apps (with Jquery, Bootstrap and just other minor plugins) that simply connect via $.ajax to functions placed in Controllers that interact with the Model/DB?

Will I go to developer hell for trying to build "pseudo" SPAs without Angularjs or Knockout and just do Raw DOM manipulations?

Also will I be able to keep my applications secure?

Any tips or references?

Comment: There is no "right way" to do anything. As long as your code solves your problem then it's right for you. Asking this kind of question will simply elicit opinions since that's what you're asking for, and will not help you in the end. You do not need to use Angular or Knockout unless they solve the problem in a more proficient manner.

Comment: There is a trade off between the advantages gained using tools like Angular, Ninject and Boostrap and the expense of writing your own code.  If it is a small project you might be able to write your own - but you'll probably regret it.  Also, secure is primarily server side.

Comment: @deek - the time to write your own versions of the features and functions for a complex web application will be significant, and when you finish you will have a pile of proprietary code that only your team will understand.  Building on existing tools almost always improves the quality of code and increases the number of people familiar with the components.

Comment: I hear you all, but at the moment we're actually regreting Angular and Ninject for our mid sized project. What we would be using are UI components from Bootstrap, JqueryUI and possibly other small ones, I have no issue with those. 
What we won't be using is Angular, React nor Knockout, and we won't be using MVC views, nor WebForms.
Will it really be that much extra code? It feels that using Angular particularly adds a lot of "very hard to understand" code.

Comment: @Voidsbane I hear ya, angular has a bit of a learning curve but it shouldn't be too hard to pick up in a few weeks. I wouldn't suggest cramming every project into angular however. Check out meteor.js too. As for extra code, it really depends....for tiny, more personnel projects, I can see how an MVC framework would cause slow down. For a bigger, long term project with many teams interacting, an MVC can be a godsend.

You might also consider making your own MVCs....some companies have did that, YMMW!!!

Comment: Yeah, I think my beef is specifically with Angular and Ninject, both of which make the application harder to maintain in the end and to play nice with other libraries like JqueryUI (in my humble opinion of course) just to gain the SPA feeling to the navigation of an App. 
But not having MVC for Layouts and simple security checks, or at least WebForms to do the same, seems like it would be a lot of unnecessary work in static htmls for any application that requires authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those MVC libraries accomplish the same but provide a framework and tools to aid development on large projects. They are not used for improved security.

Bootstrap, Zurb, and other front end frame works are a bit different; they provide out of the box front end scripts, tools, and visuals for easy deployment of interactive front end components(forms, boxes, grids). A pretty form or 3 grid column is a few lines of codes versus writing one from scratch. However, if you need to write a truly unique visual form, you may want to write one from scratch then just modifying a bootstrap one.